# How to make an OPTIONS request in Dart?

Tags: dart, server, httprequest

If I use the HttpClient or http library I can make `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE` and other requests, but I don't see anything for making an `OPTIONS` request. I can't even figure out how to send a generic request by typing in the method name as a string. The reason I want it is for testing my server that gets OPTIONS requests sometimes.

This is how I make a POST request:

```dart
final response = await http.post(url, headers: postHeaders, body: postBody);
```

How would I make an OPTIONS request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to do like so:

```dart
import 'package:http/http.dart';

final client = Client();
final method = 'OPTIONS';
final url = Uri.parse('http://www.example.com');
final request = Request(method, url);
final streamedResponse = await client.send(request);
final response = await Response.fromStream(streamedResponse);
print(response.statusCode);
```

Comment: is it possible to add headers to the request?

Comment: @perrohunter, I would guess so but I'm not sure off hand without doing more testing. If you discover the answer, please leave another comment or add another answer.